# Hostname www.kdrc.ru not verified:

Tags: java, android, яндекс-почта

После переноса почты с гугл на яндекс (используется свой домен), нет доступа к серверной части из приложения android. При отправке запроса, например POST, пишет следующую ошибку:

```
Hostname www.kdrc.ru not verified:
        certificate: sha256/lxy8OofWytTcB8Bi5yHrGOo12RSFQ1OIOWw+qWiHeUo=
        DN: CN=mail.yandex.ru,O=Yandex LLC,OU=ITO,L=Moscow,C=RU
        subjectAltNames: [mail.yandex.ru, mail.yandex.co.il, mail.yandex.com.ua, mail.yandex.com, mail.yandex.tj, mail.yandex.by, mail.ya.ru, xn--80a1acny.xn--d1acpjx3f.xn--p1ai, mail.yandex.com.am, mail.yandex.com.ge, posta.yandex.com.tr, mail.yandex.az, mail.yandex.kg, mail.yandex.md, mail.yandex.kz, mail.yandex.tm, mail.yandex.uz, mail.yandex.ua, mail.yandex.lv, mail.yandex.lt, mail.yandex, mail.yandex.fr, mail.yandex.com.tr, mail.yandex.ee]
```

При отправке того же запроса через компьютер, таких проблем не возникает. Что я не учел при переносе почты и как это можно исправить?

Код:

```
IDrinkShopAPI mService= RetrofitClient.getClient("http://www.kdrc.ru/drinkshop/").create(IDrinkShopAPI.class);
    CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
    compositeDisposable.add(mService.getNearbyStore(String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLatitude()),
            String.valueOf(lastLocation.getLongitude()))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<List<Store>>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(List<Store> stores) throws Exception {

                for (Store store : stores) {
                    LatLng storeLocation = new LatLng(store.getLat(), store.getLng());
                }
        }
    }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
//Здесь происходит указанное выше сообщение
            Log.d("123", throwable.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

IDrinkShopAPI.java:

```
public interface IDrinkShopAPI {
        @FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("getnearbystore.php")
        Observable<List<Store>> getNearbyStore(@Field("lat") String lat,
                                               @Field("lng") String lng);
    }
```

RetrofitClient.java

```
public class RetrofitClient {
    private static Retrofit retrofit=null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseUrl){
        if(retrofit==null){
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();
            retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31917988

Comment: прочитал, но не понял, можно пояснить?

Comment: а можно тогда кусок кода, работающий с почтой?

Comment: работы с почтой в коде нет, я просто указал после чего случилась проблема, в коде  получаю данные из БД. На хостинге менял dns-записи на яндексовские.

Answer (score 0):

Решилось всё довольно просто.
При запросе на [www.kdrc.ru](http://www.kdrc.ru) не работало вследствие криво прописанных мной dns-записей.
И был выбор либо убрать www, либо исправить dns-записи.
Помогли исправить dns в техподдержке хостинг-кампании.